# How to center my ':after' background-image?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image which covers the full width and height of the browser. When opening the html file on a smaller screen, only the left side of the image is visible.

What I want is to scale and center the image on the background. What do I have to change in my css code?

```
div#background-content {
    position: relative;
}

div#background-content:after {
    background-image:url('./images/sunrise.jpg');
    opacity:0.7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    content : "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this code in your css:

```
 div#background-content:after {
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position):

`background-position: center;`

Answer (score 0):

add background-position: center;
i recomended to you use `background:url('./images/sunrise.jpg') no-repeat center;`

Answer (score 0):

```
div#background-content:after{
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div#background-content:after {
background-image:url('./images/sunrise.jpg');
opacity:0.7;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: left -206px top -95px !important;
background-size: 320% 110% !important;
display:block;
content : "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
```

}